# Cascade variadic template template parameters

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-templates

How can I cascade variadic types? I.e.:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
using Cascade = ???; // T1<T2<T3<...>>>
```

Example:

```cpp
using Vector2D = Cascade<std::vector, std::vector, double>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Vector2D, std::vector<std::vector<double>>>);
```

Comment: You cannot CascadeRight. `T1` is not a typename, it is a template, and so are most of the others, but the last one is a typename. You cannot have different parameter kinds in the same variadic list.

Comment: Write a class. Overload the class for number of template arguments. For each overload add a `using type =` with proper implemenation.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.
That isn't correct; variadic templates allow any number of different types.

Comment: @radj Go ahead, write `CascadeRight` then. (I said *kinds* not *types*. "Kind" is a technical term. "Types" is a kind, and "class templates" is a different kind.)

Comment: I guess the terms left and right don't make sense for cascading as they do for folding - reworded the question

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Ah, I misunderstood then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have CascadeRight. T1 is not a typename, it is a template, and so are most of the others, but the last one is a typename. You cannot have different parameter kinds (both types and templates) in the same parameter pack. You also cannot have anything after a parameter pack.

You can have CascadeLeft like this:

```
  template <typename K, template <typename...> class ... T>
  class CascadeLeft;                  
                                      
  template <typename K>               
  class CascadeLeft<K>                
  {                                   
      using type = K;                 
  };                                  
                                      
  template <typename K, 
            template <typename...> class T0, 
            template <typename...> class... T>
  class CascadeLeft<K, T0, T...>      
  {                                   
      using type = typename CascadeLeft<T0<K>, T...>::type;
  };
```

Frankly, `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` is much more transparent than `CascadeLeft<double, std::vector, std::vector>`, so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: It would be `CascadeRight` if you change unpacking to `using type = T0<typename CascadeLeft<K, T...>::type>;`, no?

Comment: Yes but then the innermost type parameter is the first one, the next-innermost the last one, and the outermost is the second one. Very confusing.

Comment: Indeed, but it can be implemented as somehing like `CascadeRight<std::vector, std::map>::type<int, double>`

Comment: Yes it can, but why?

Comment: I prefer `CascadeRight` because the order is the same as with nesting and thus more intuitive. As for why I need cascading in the first place - I needed to chain 6 type decorators (`remove_const` and the like), which looks cleaner as a list. Also, the list is the only option if I ever needed to conditionally disable some of them with `#if`.

Comment: Anyway, at some point I decided that's overengineering, and the reasons became purely academic

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the accepted answer with `CascadeRight` and support for multiple types for the innermost template:

```cpp
template<template<typename...> typename Head, template<typename...> typename... Tail>
struct CascadeRight {
    template<typename... T>
    using type = Head<typename CascadeRight<Tail...>::type<T...>>;
};

template<template<typename...> typename Head>
struct CascadeRight<Head> {
    template<typename... T>
    using type = Head<T...>;
};

template<template<typename...> typename Head, template<typename...> typename... Tail>
struct CascadeLeft {
    template<typename... T>
    using type = typename CascadeLeft<Tail...>::type<Head<T...>>;
};

template<template<typename...> typename Head>
struct CascadeLeft<Head> {
    template<typename... T>
    using type = Head<T...>;
};
```

```cpp
using T1 = CascadeRight<std::vector, std::map>::type<int, double>;
using T2 = CascadeLeft<std::map, std::vector>::type<int, double>;
```